# Why is it that I program in VB.NET but the website is actually in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm programming in VB.NET, yet the site is in ASP.NET. How does that work? Does it have to do with something called server side language?

Comment: As people said below, ASP.NET is the UI Tech, and any .NET language could be used and even mixed because at the end they all turn to .NET "byte code", is it right guys? So doesnt matter the language, as they will be "translated" to the same "byte code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET is the web platform, it can use any .NET language.

When someone programs an ASP.NET site with C#, that's the language used in the code behind (page.aspx.cs) files.

For VB.NET the code behind files are in VB.NET (page.aspx.vb).

Comment: VB.NET is to ASP.NET as... VBScript is to ASP Classic as... Ruby is to Ruby On Rails. ASP.NET is the Platform, while VB.NET is the Language. Although, ASP.NET also uses an HTML/XHTML like markup (via server tags) to perform some declarative programming too.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is the UI technology. VB.NET is the programming language.

You can mix and match. You can use VB.NET for ASP.NET, or Windows Forms, or WPF, or Silverlight, or console applications, or XNA. You can also use C#, or F#, or IronPython, or any other .NET language with most or all of those technologies.

Comment: It is much more than a UI technology.

Comment: @Oded, of course you're right, but I figured "UI technology" was a good first approximation at explaining the difference to a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is a server side scripting technology that enables scripts (embedded in web pages) to be executed by an Internet server. If a browser requests an ASP.NET page, the server processes any executable code in the page( on VB or C# ), before the result is sent back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is a framework that provides you a tool set that allows you to develop web sites / applications. It is like the Window Forms which is also a different framework that is provided to you by Microsoft to allow you to develop windows applications.

VB.NET and C# are both .NET just programming languages that you can use to write code against these frameworks. Whichever .Net language you choose doesn't really matter since it is converted by the CLR into machine code.